# Pyqtgraph plots not showing inside Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, pyqtgraph

Inside Pycharm (v 2016.1.2), on Ubuntu 15, when i run

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
data = np.random.normal(size=(500,2))
pg.plot(data)
```

I get output

```
Out[10]: <pyqtgraph.graphicsWindows.PlotWindow at 0x7f61de0c0798>
```

And a blank window. However, when I run the same commands from python3 runniing from Ubuntu terminal, it runs fine. I also noted that if I run Pycharm from terminal, I get the following warning which may/may not be relevant

```
[   7103]  ERROR - napi.project.CacheUpdateRunner - PyCharm 2016.1.2  Build #PY-145.844.6 
[   7103]  ERROR - napi.project.CacheUpdateRunner - JDK: 1.8.0_76-release 
[   7104]  ERROR - napi.project.CacheUpdateRunner - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
[   7104]  ERROR - napi.project.CacheUpdateRunner - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
[   7104]  ERROR - napi.project.CacheUpdateRunner - OS: Linux 
[   7104]  ERROR - napi.project.CacheUpdateRunner - Last Action:  
[   8658]   WARN - napi.components.ServiceManager - com.jetbrains.python.console.PythonConsoleRunnerFactory requested as a service, but it is a component - convert it to a service or change call to ApplicationManager.getApplication().getComponent(). I would really like to keep using Pycharm, so if anyone has a remedy please let me know. Thanks.
```

Comment: I have found a workaround: If i first load matplotlib (i added a configuration file which ensures it uses Qt4Agg as backend and not Qt5Agg), the plots open fine.